# How to except database transaction submit for a model in Django?

Tags: python, django, transactions, pusher

Example I have two models:

```
class Customer:
    ...

class ImportResult:
    ...
```

What happen is I would like to import `Customer` from file to our database and update the `ImportResult` progress. Here the sample code:

```
with transaction.atomic():
   Customer.objects.create(**data)
   import_result.update_progress()
   import_result.save()
```

The problem is that because `import_result` also inside transaction I cannot get the progress at the time it updated. The data only submit to database when transaction completed. Noted that when `update_progress()` called we used `Pusher` to update the web in realtime. So the question is are there anyway to excepting or force `import_result` to commit to database right away?

Comment: This question needs some more detail. `import_result` appears to be a model instance. Do you mean that `update_progress()` runs in a transaction? What is "the progress"? Is it a database field on `ImportResult`? Where are you trying to get that value and use it before the transaction finishes? I don't see that in the code you posted.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry `import_result` run in side a transaction with `Customer` model. And yes `progress` is a field `import_result` sample data should be `['Step 1 completed', 'Step 2 is failed', 'Import Failed']`. So the progress is already saved what I do is send `import_result` id to frontend(angular) via `Pusher` so frontend only need to call `/api/import_result/id/` to get updated data, but since it's in side the transaction it yet commit to database, so I cannot get the latest data.

Comment: Basically, the answer is no. You can't have it both ways. If you want the progress to be updated with failures, it doesn't make sense to put that update inside a transaction that will be rolled back in case of failure. Why do you have the `transaction.atomic()` at all in the code above?

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry Because I need to to rollback `Customer` model is there is anything failed. At the same I need to update the progress.

Comment: The only way to get what you want is to put the update code in a separate transaction, which means a separate database connection. Django does not support that directly, but if you look around there is [some](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-users/5TRPydzRiJg/9RLMWbU4xiwJ) [information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12372320/2395796) about it.